# R merging Quarterly data with first date of quarter as the index

Tags: r, quantmod

I can generate quarterly OHLC date from a daily time series:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2000-01-01", to=Sys.Date())
tail(SPY)
dfQ <- to.quarterly(SPY[,6])
tail(dfQ)
```

I can also generate the quarterly mean:

```
dfmean1 <- apply.quarterly(xts(SPY[,6]), FUN = mean)
tail(dfmean1)
```

However I am having problems merging the two, with an index showing the first date of the quarter (rather than the last date of the quarter).

Thank you for your help

Comment: The mean for the quarter isn't known until the end of the quarter. You're likely to introduce significant bias if you change the timestamp to the beginning of the quarter. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: I need to do this as I have a number of other data series that are indexed by the start of the quarter and not by the end of the quarter

Comment: It the data in those other series are for the end of the quarter, wouldn't it make more sense to move their timestamp to the end of the quarter?

Comment: That is a possible solution, but I do not know how to convert the first date of the quarter to the last date. I apologize for my ignorance as it is probably something I should know how to do.

Comment: Use `yearqtr`: `as.Date(as.yearqtr(Sys.Date())+.25)-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two questions here. The first is how to have a mean column in OHLC quarterly data. The second is how to have datestamps for the start of each quarter, instead of "last" datestamps. The xts/quantmod packages assume you want "last" datestamps, so go with the flow, and just replace the datestamps at the end.

To have mean with OHLC I've found it best just to do the OHLC calculation myself. So instead of passing `mean` to `apply.quarterly()`, do this:

```
bars = apply.quarterly(xts(SPY[,6]), FUN = function(x){
  d=coredata(x);
  c(first(d),max(d),min(d),last(d),mean(d))
  } )
colnames(bars)=c("open","high","low","close","mean")
```

This gives:

```
...
2013-09-30 159.71 171.28 159.56 167.10 165.9822
2013-12-31 168.43 184.69 164.59 184.69 176.1416
2014-01-08 182.92 183.52 182.36 183.52 183.0340
```

Then to fix the datestamps:

```
index(bars) = as.Date(as.yearqtr(index(bars)))
```

To understand that, start by looking at `index(bars)`, then look at `as.yearqtr(index(bars))`, which gives:

```
[1] "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3" ...
   ... "2013 Q3" "2013 Q4" "2014 Q1"
```

Then, as luck would have it, `as.Date()` gives you the datestamp of the start of each quarter.

The final bit is to assign the new index back to the `bars` object with `index(bars) = ...`  (or `index(bars) <- ...` if you prefer).

---

By the way, there is also a `indexAt="lastof"` or `indexAt="firstof"` parameter you could give to `to.quarterly()`. Experiment with this, but in my tests it was not quite useful enough.